# Android Studio 3.0 issues - find and replace all have changed

Tags: android-studio

With 3.0 both Ctl-F and Ctl-R behavior have changed.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

The problem is linked with partial search of a word. This used to work nicely with 2.3.

[image]
Examples:

1. Ctl-F: if I have a variable call used and I type us, the search field is red. I must search for the complete word.
2. Ctl-R: same problem as Ctl-F. You copy paste an xml layout and you just need to change part of an Id everywhere in the file. You can't do that anymore: when you select part of the word CtlR doesn't find the sub-string.

Or is there some new ways of doing?

Comment: Uncheck _Words_ option...

Comment: where do you find this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck Words option in right hand side of search bar. 
Refer the image

[image: refer image]

Comment: got it! I did not think that was a cool feature to have. Strange it is set by default when upgrading. Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) nrab